# Package install missing S3 methods

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, dtw

I'm trying to install the R package "dtwclust". It has worked for me as recently as 6 months ago, but now--presumably due to a system update, R update, or package update--I get the following error message:

```
install.packages("dtwclust")
```

...

```
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods ‘eigs.matrix’, ‘eigs.dgeMatrix’, ‘eigs.dgCMatrix’, 
‘eigs.dgRMatrix’, ‘eigs.dsyMatrix’, ‘eigs.function’, 
‘eigs_sym.matrix’, ‘eigs_sym.dgeMatrix’, ‘eigs_sym.dgCMatrix’, 
‘eigs_sym.dgRMatrix’, ‘eigs_sym.function’, ‘svds.matrix’, 
‘svds.dgeMatrix’, ‘svds.dgCMatrix’, ‘svds.dgRMatrix’, m 
‘svds.dsyMatrix’, ‘svds.function’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not 
found
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
undefined exports: eigs, eigs_sym, svds
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried using the dependencies = TRUE argument, and I've tried reinstalling r-base. Any idea where these missing S3 methods are? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to reinstall RSpectra. See [this](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What_0027s-the-best-way-to-upgrade_003f) for how to update packages after R upgrade, and coincidentally also [this](https://github.com/asardaes/dtwclust/issues/30) GitHub issue.